# Framework7-vue: how to disable built-in router?

Tags: html-framework-7

I'm using `Framework7` with the `Framework7-vue` extension.

This comes with a built-in router, but I want to use `vue-router` instead.

Is there any way to disable the built-in router of `Framework7-vue` ?

Answer (score -1):

Recently I've done a project with `framwork7-vue` and `vue-router`. I just ignored the built-in router of `framework7`. It worked 99% of the time. Some of the animations(such as switching tabs) are coupled with built-in router. If you don't use it, you won't be able to have those animations. It is the 1% which didn't work for me.

Comment: The built-in router does not change url in address bar, so whatever view it currently renders, the url is always the same. In dev mode, if I change some code, the page will not refresh automatically. This is the major reason I want to rollback to default `vue-router`.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 Yes as I said, I used vue-router and it worked 99.9% of the time. framework7-router does have some issues.

Comment: How do you disable/ignore?

Comment: @Victor It has been a long time and I don't remember the details. But to ignore it simply means do not use it, use vue-router instead.